# Как поставить флаги для конфига None в CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake

По дефолту `cmake` использует build type None. Как для него поставить флаги (не меняя сорсы)? `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_None` и `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_NONE` не работают. Просто `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` меняет все флаги, а мне надо только для этого конфига.

Comment: А что вы в `-G` передаете?

Answer (score 0):

Это невозможно сделать, т.к. None нельзя кастомизировать, поэтому используйте какой-нибудь неиспользуемый в CMakeLists.txt тип билда и ставьте флаги для него. Например, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING="-O42"`. Либо используйте используемый, но дублируйте флаги из CMakeLists.txt, которые не хотите менять.